# Pushcart Food Vendor in Fort Worth

Tags: usa, food-and-drink, regulations

I am thinking to start working with food pushcart in Fort Worth, TX. Before anything, I believe I need to learn about all legal aspects. I have found [this site](https://fortworthtexas.gov/health/MobileVendors/) but I cannot open it. There is also [this](https://www.dshs.texas.gov/foodestablishments/permitting.aspx) site that is about Texas in general and gives not much details.

So is there any source about regulation and other legal stuff I can read and learn?

Edit: I am not sure the question belongs here or other community page, so sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: What is your nationality?  Are you asking on how to migrate to the US in order to be a push cart food vendor?  Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @gerrit I am not asking how to migrate to the States. I am asking; a) what is the source for regulations and b) is there any additional instructions for legal foreigners?

Comment: (a) is off-topic and question (b) is not apparent from your question

Comment: @gerrit Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You might try using a computer at a library to access the page and linked pdf documents.

Comment: @mkennedy The site looks like down. Can you reach it?

Comment: yes, using Chrome on a desktop computer. Chrome does report that the site isn't 100% secure (certificate is good though) so maybe your browser is blocking it?